# NameError: name 'openFile' is not defined

Tags: python, function, nameerror

This may be a dumb questions but I'm new at programming with Python. I've research but I'm not able to find the reason why my Funcion 'openFile(self,file)' is not found.

It's a simple Tkinter program where I need to create a Excel File and have it automatically open after creating it. (My Own Project)

When I remove the function "openFile" the Excel file is created correctly. As soon as I add the 'openFile" function it comes up that "Name is not define" as though it doesn't exist. I have never been able to figure out why that happens.

I appreciate all your help!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Text, filedialog
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
class notepad:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.root = window

        self.menubar = Menu(self.root)
        self.root.config(menu = self.menubar)
        self.fileMenu = Menu(self.menubar, tearoff =0)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = self.fileMenu)
        self.fileMenu.add_command(label = "New", command = self.New_File)
        self.fileMenu.add_command(label = "Open")
        self.fileMenu.add_command(label = "Exit")

        name = Label(self.root, text = "Name")
        name.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        lname = Label(self.root, text = "Last Name")
        lname.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

        phone = Label(self.root, text = "Phone number")
        phone.grid(row = 3, column = 1)


        tname = StringVar()
        tlname = StringVar()
        tphone = StringVar()

        self.namebox = Entry(self.root, textvariable = tname)
        self.namebox.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

        self.lnamebox = Entry(self.root, textvariable =tlname )
        self.lnamebox.grid(row = 2, column = 2)

        self.phonebox = Entry(self.root, textvariable = tphone)
        self.phonebox.grid(row = 3, column = 2)

        self.button = Button(self.root, text = "Save")
        self.button.grid(row = 4, columnspan = 3)


    def New_File(self):
        raw_file_name = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir = "/Excel_File_Test", title = "Select 
        Directory", filetypes = (('Excel File', '*.xlsm'),("All Fiesl","*.*")))

        raw_file_name = raw_file_name +'.xlsx'
        workbook = Workbook()
        sheet = workbook.active

        sheet ["A1"] = "Name"
        sheet ["B1"] = "Last Name"


        workbook.save(filename = raw_file_name)
        openFile(raw_file_name)

    def openFile(self,file):
        with load_workbook(filename =file) as workbook:
            print(workbook + " has load up correctly") #this message just to confirm the file loads correctly

window = Tk()
application = notepad(window)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

The function `openFile` is part of you class.  You should reference to `self.openFile`:

Try this:

```
def New_File(self):
    ...
    workbook.save(filename = raw_file_name)
    self.openFile(raw_file_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `openFile(raw_file_name)` with `self.openFile(raw_file_name)` and that error will be gone.

Comment: You are the Man! Thanks A lot! :D